# Is there an iOS-accessible API to detect a drunk person?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to detect if a person is drunk via image recognition or face-scanning? If it's possible, is there an API available for that?

Comment: I'd think using the accelerometer would be more reliable than face detection?

Comment: There are apps to calculate BAC based on weight, gender, number of drinks, etc.  But short of taking a blood, breath or urine test you are just estimating.

Comment: @bbum wow the accelerometer one was good. :-)

Comment: I know the question sounds very funny, but that's why I'm asking because I'm interested to know if it's possible.


Accelerometer will have to do with the motion/tilting of the device. But what I would like to know is if it's possible using face-scanning. :)

Comment: Interesting: http://news.discovery.com/tech/apps/drunk-driving-app-120107.htm *...a new app for the iPhone called BreathalEyes, which detects involuntary eye movement to let potential drunk drivers know when they've had a few too many.* It's really unlikely to have an an API available, though.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta wow really funny! but that proves that someone else could code something similar, in other words, it *IS* possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to code again the accelerometer. Maybe a drunk person is unable to hold the phone still??

http://www.technobuffalo.com/2011/05/15/introduction-to-ios-development-playing-with-the-accelerometer/

Answer (score 1):

This is a RESTful face recognition api and maybe what you want http://www.faceplusplus.com . But I don't know whether it can detect drunk face.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV! [Haartraining!](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#e134e74e)

> *FYI: I recommend you to work haartraining with something different concurrently because you have to wait so many days during training (it would possibly take one week). I typically experimented as 1. run haartraining on Friday 2. forget about it completely 3. see results on next Friday 4. run another haartraining (loop).*